# Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement in MS Access 2010

Tags: ms-access-2010

Im using Access 2010 when I try to input this syntax:

```
INSERT INTO Order ( ClientId, ProductID, EmployeeID, DeliveryID )
VAlUES ('1', '8', '3' '1');
```

It says syntax error in insert order statement. I used the same syntax in inserting record to my other tables and it works.

Comment: A comma is missing between the two last values.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a missing comma between the 2 last arguments.

Bye!